# Grails testing criterias/ GORM in unit test or integration test?

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I read that in Grails, some complex GORM operations, criteria. queries does not work in unit tests.

Should we just put in all tests that involves database queries in integration tests? Is that ok in a "best practice" sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some queries don't work, and since the backing store for the in-memory GORM implementation used in unit tests is a `ConcurrentHashMap` and not a database, important features like locking and transactions are not supported.

Always use integration tests for persistence, at a minimum using the H2 in-memory database but ideally using the same database that you use for your app, i.e. a test schema in MySQL/Postgres/Oracle/etc.